# snakemake has issue with using singularity

Tags: sandbox, snakemake

```
[Tue Jan  9 13:58:00 2024]
rule salmon_index:
    input: transcriptome/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.cdna.all.fa.gz
    output: Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index
    jobid: 0
    reason: Missing output files: Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index
    wildcards: strain=Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

salmon index -t transcriptome/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.cdna.all.fa.gz -i Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index -k 29
Activating singularity image salmon-1.10.2.sif
/usr/local/packages/Modules/4.5.0/init/bash: line 37: /usr/bin/tclsh: No such file or directory
INFO:    Converting SIF file to temporary sandbox...
FATAL:   while extracting salmon-1.10.2.sif: root filesystem extraction failed: extract command failed: ERROR  : Failed to create user namespace: user namespace disabled
: exit status 1
[Tue Jan  9 13:58:00 2024]
Error in rule salmon_index:
    jobid: 0
    input: transcriptome/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.cdna.all.fa.gz
    output: Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index
    shell:
        salmon index -t transcriptome/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.cdna.all.fa.gz -i Saccharomyces_cerevisiae.R64-1-1.salmon_index -k 29
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2024-01-09T135759.206079.snakemake.log
```

It is always trying to build sandbox in this cluster

how to solve this problem? How to avoid it converting SIF file to temporary sandbox...

Comment: Possibly related to a [full home directory](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/issues/482)?